# Why strictness makes performance worse in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I played with strict evaluations, vectors and matrices and got a rather strange result. There is the following code:

```
module Test where

import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Matrix as M

import Control.DeepSeq

matrixCtor :: Int -> Int -> Int -> M.Matrix Int
matrixCtor x y size = M.matrix size size $ \(i,j) -> x*i+y*j

f :: M.Matrix Int -> M.Matrix Int
f b = c
  where
    n = M.nrows b
    bt' = V.generate n $ \j -> M.getCol (j+1) b
    c = M.matrix n n $ \(i,j) -> V.sum  (V.unsafeIndex bt' (j-1))
```

I load it into ghci and perform the following actions:

```
*Main Test> :set +s
*Main Test> a = matrixCtor 1 2 800
(0.02 secs, 0 bytes)
*Main Test> f a `deepseq` 1
1
(6.69 secs, 8,684,393,584 bytes)
```

Then I tried so:

```
*Main Test> a = matrixCtor 1 2 800
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
*Main Test> a `deepseq` 1
1
(0.35 secs, 220,646,904 bytes)
*Main Test> f a `deepseq` 1
1
(9.72 secs, 8,484,723,352 bytes)
*Main Test>
```

In the second version, I calculate the matrix in advance and it seemed to me that the execution of the function `f` should be accelerated, but this did't happen. I can't understand why.

Comment: When you benchmark it should be with compiled code that uses at least `-O1`.  Anything else, particularly using ghci, is meaningless.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I agree. But I'm more interested in the ratio of these times. Why is the strict version so slower here? 
This is not the only test. I constantly get about this ratio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to work to improve the performance of GHCi then I commend that, but a benchmark in GHCi is not something you can use to reason about the performance of the code in basically any other setting.  The performance numbers you see are only meaningful in your one narrow context.

For example, when you translate your code into a criterion benchmark and comipile with optimization you'll see the strict version performing better, not worse:

```
benchmarking first
time                 5.808 s    (4.995 s .. 6.718 s)
                     0.996 R²   (0.995 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 5.237 s    (4.931 s .. 5.452 s)
std dev              325.5 ms   (0.0 s .. 374.0 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking second
time                 5.276 s    (4.576 s .. 6.089 s)
                     0.997 R²   (0.990 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 5.070 s    (4.817 s .. 5.212 s)
std dev              224.0 ms   (0.0 s .. 244.9 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)
```